# sql compare tables using like

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to compare two tables in sql using the LIKE command in another table.

Table1

```
accountNumber     description
12345             wires sent out
```

Table2

```
keywords
wire
fund
fee
```

so I am trying to say, give me all the records in table1, that table1.description are LIKE records in table2.keywords

does this make sense?  then I am trying to do the reverse... give me all records in table1, that are NOT LIKE table2.keywards.

I have tried this line but it's not working

```
left join dbo.cashkeywords cashkeyTable on cashkeyTable.keyword like xxxTable.PSDSC1
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Cross Apply:

```
declare @Table1 table ([accountNumber] int, [description] nvarchar(100))
insert into @Table1 values (12345, 'wires sent out')

declare @Table2 table ([keywords] nvarchar(100))
insert into @Table2 values 
('wire')
,('fund')
,('fee')

select distinct *
from @Table1 t1
cross apply @Table2 t2
where t1.description like '%' + t2.keywords + '%'
```

For single returns:

```
select distinct t1.*
from @Table1 t1
cross apply @Table2 t2
where t1.description like '%' + t2.keywords + '%'
```

Comment: thanks... so this seems to be the right path but there is a little glitch.  some results are being returned twice.  here is one specific example.. table1description is FUNDS RECD... in my keyword table I have fund, rec.   could it be returning this twice because 2 diff words are in keywords?

Comment: @solarissf Yes. It cannot show the keyword if you want single rows. I have added the single row option.

Comment: the single returns option seems to be working with my first sample set... thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

Presumably, you need wildcards.  In standard SQL, this would look like:

```
left join
dbo.cashkeywords cashkeyTable
on cashkeyTable.keyword like '%' || xxxTable.PSDSC1 || '%'
```

Hmmm . . . that shoudl be probably really:

```
on ?.keywordlist like '%' || ?.keyword || '%'
```

It is a bit hard to tell from your naming which is which.  You might also want to include delimiters.

For the exclusion, you then want `where ?.keyword is null`.

String concatenation functions/operators can differ among databases, so this might not be the exact syntax for your database.

As an aside, storing lists of values in a single column is a really bad idea.  You should have a sepeate table with on row per keyword, rather than stuffing all the keywords into one column.

Comment: I will edit question to give more details... table2, has 1 column, with different records of keywords

Comment: I just tried this and ALL rows are being returned... so something is off.   FROM dbo.xxx xxxTable left join dbo.cashkeywords cashkeyTable on cashkeyTable.keyword like '%' + xxxTable.PSDSC1 + '%'